# Search a string for a value

Tags: c#, string

I have a string where its formatted with delimeters like:

```
string | time stamp in milliseconds | int counter | string
```

I need to be able to grab the counter value only. There will be a number of messages so the time stamp and counter will increase with each message.
I am using a string builder for the incoming messages.

What is the best way to get the counter in each string message coming in?

```
sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
string content = sb.ToString();
```

Thank you

Comment: [`content.Split(" | ")[2]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

Comment: Yeah sorry, that should have been an array of char instead of a string. Basically, see Hassan's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If string is coming like this:

```
string strContent = "abc|1399718438000|100|def";
```

You could use [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method

```
int iCounter = Convert.ToInt32(strContent.Split(new char[] {'|'})[2]);
```

Or preferably when dealing with single char for splitting a string.

```
int iCounter = Convert.ToInt32(strContent.Split('|')[2]);
```

Comment: Note that since you're passing a char instead of a string, and the parameter is `params`, you don't need to explicitly new up an array. `strContent.Split('|')` would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
int counter = Convert.ToInt32(strContent.Split('|').ToList().ElementAt(2));
```

Comment: Why use `ToList().ElementAt` instead of just directly accessing `[2]`? What's the point?

Answer (score 0):

Split is a little heavy here. Just get indexes of the second and the third separator and use SubString to get the counter part.